# Are there any active Classical Latin users nowadays?

Tags: latin, dead-languages, language-revival

Are there any groups of active Classical Latin users nowadays?

By *active* I mean they meet regularly and speak in classical Latin, or make some videos/vlogs/podcasts or present lectures.

Comment: For what value of 'Classical'? Pronunciation-wise, grammar-wise, vocabulary-wise, or all of the above? I do know there are a lot of active Latin users nowadays, though for practical reasons there is a lot of neo-Latin. You can probably find people at [Vicipaedia](http://la.wikipedia.org/).

Comment: I've meant pronunciation, since it is the most distinguishing feature (compared to Church Latin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are Nuntii Latini, of Radiophonia Finnica Generalis, who bring Latin news. I don't know whether they are still active, though. E.g., here on the arrest of Ratko Mladic: http://areena.yle.fi/radio/1278942

There is also the Bremen Latin news: http://www.radiobremen.de/nachrichten/latein/

EDIT: The French website [mediterranees.net/latin_vivant.html](http://www.mediterranees.net/latin_vivant.html) has many links, including both of my above.

Comment: Yle has updated its pages, so the current link is http://yle.fi/radio1/tiede/nuntii_latini/

Comment: The Latin news from Radio Bremen are now at https://www.bremenzwei.de/themen/nuntii-latini-100.html

Answer (score 0):

Thomas Bervoets, whom got me into classical Latin in the first place. I recommend listening to him the most:

- https://www.stilus.nl/horatius/index.htm#6
- https://www.stilus.nl/ce-geluid/index.htm
- https://www.stilus.nl/catilina/index.htm
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmn69Xga7Mg&t=309s

The Finnish female Classical Latin news announcer of the Finnish Nuntii Latini: https://areena.yle.fi/audio/1-1931339

And the lady on [YouTube video called "Classical Latin VS Vulgar Latin- What's the difference?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OdQawsU2RFg&t=309s) saying the Classical Latin sentence "Marcus patrī librum dat."